# How to get the first 11 bits of a 32 bit int with ctypes

Tags: python, ctypes, bit-fields

How do I get the first 11 bits of a 32 bit int with `ctypes`?

```
import ctypes

class Fields(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('a', ctypes.c_uint, 11)]

class BitField(ctypes.Union):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('b', Fields),
                ('raw', ctypes.c_uint)]

bf = BitField()
bf.raw = 0b01010000001000000000000000000001

print('0b{:0>32b}'.format(bf.raw))
print('0b{:0>32b}'.format(bf.b.a))
```

Result:

```
0b01010000001000000000000000000001
0b00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Whereas I wanted

```
0b01010000001000000000000000000001
0b00000000000000000000001010000001
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you wanted. Is the first output ok? I'm not seeing a difference there.

Comment: The first line is 32 bit number unchanged, I just print it for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option could be to use

```
class Fields(ctypes.Structure):
    _pack_ = 1
    _fields_ = [('x', ctypes.c_uint, 21), ('a', ctypes.c_uint, 11)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit field implementations vary wildly. If you want to extract specific bits from an integers (instead of interoperating with a C library's `struct`), you're better off avoiding ctypes entirely and using bitwise operations:

```
raw = 0b01010000001000000000000000000001
a = raw >> (32 - 11)
```

Comment: This is what I normally do, but I wanted to see if `ctypes` was faster.